# How to sort this List of Dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, tf-idf

```
def searchSimilarDocumentsByPhrases(corpus, Ids, contractIds,count,phrases=None):
  tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(vocabulary = phrases, ngram_range=(1, 6))
  tfs = tfidf.fit_transform(corpus)
  feature_names = tfidf.get_feature_names_out()
  rows, cols = tfs.nonzero()

  phrase_counts = defaultdict(list)
  for row, col in zip(rows, cols):
    phraseCount = corpus[row].count(feature_names[col])
    phrase_counts[feature_names[col]].append({Ids[row]:{contractIds[row]: phraseCount}})

  counter=count
  phraselist=[]
  for phrase, counts in phrase_counts.items():
    counts.sort(key=lambda x: list(x.items()), reverse=True) 
    counts=counts[:counter]
    phraselist.append(phrase)
    phraselist.append(counts)
  return phraselist
```

Input provided by me is

```
{ "phrases":
 [
  "test and evaluation"
 ],
 "count":"16"
}
```

I am getting Output as

[
"test and evaluation",
[
{
"1180": {
"LMLB_C-157": 4
}
},
{
"1179": {
"LMLB_C-156": 1
}
},
{
"1156": {
"LMLB_C-135": 1
}
},
{
"1146": {
"LMLB_C-125": 2
}
},
{
"1103": {
"LMLB_C-82": 3
}
},
{
"1099": {
"LMLB_C-78": 1
}
},
{
"1089": {
"LMLB_C-68": 2
}
},
{
"1088": {
"LMLB_C-67": 1
}
},
{
"1087": {
"LMLB_C-66": 1
}
},
{
"1084": {
"LMLB_C-63": 1
}
},
{
"1080": {
"LMLB_C-59": 21
}
},
{
"1078": {
"LMLB_C-57": 1
}
},
{
"1076": {
"LMLB_C-55": 2
}
},
{
"1071": {
"LMLB_C-50": 2
}
},
{
"64": {
"LMLB_C-41": 2
}
},
{
"24": {
"LMLB_C-2": 1
}
}
],

While I expect the Output to be like below Descending order of the values

```
[
    "test and evaluation",
    [
        {
            "1080": {
                "LMLB_C-59": 21
            }
        },
        {
            "1180": {
                "LMLB_C-157": 4
            }
        },
        {
            "1103": {
                "LMLB_C-82": 3
            }
        },
        {
            "1076": {
                "LMLB_C-55": 2
            }
        },
        {
            "1071": {
                "LMLB_C-50": 2
            }
        },
        {
            "1089": {
                "LMLB_C-68": 2
            }
        },
        {
            "1146": {
                "LMLB_C-125": 2
            }
        },
        {
            "64": {
                "LMLB_C-41": 2
            }
        },
      {
            "24": {
                "LMLB_C-2": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "1088": {
                "LMLB_C-67": 1
            }
        },


        {
            "1078": {
                "LMLB_C-57": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "1156": {
                "LMLB_C-135": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "1099": {
                "LMLB_C-78": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "1087": {
                "LMLB_C-66": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "1084": {
                "LMLB_C-63": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "1179": {
                "LMLB_C-156": 1
            }
        },

    ]
```

P.S. I have edited the Input and Output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a built in function for string natural sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort) I.e. `counts = natsort.natsorted(counts, reverse=True)`

Comment: If you don't want to use a 3rd party package, then `counts.sort(key=lambda x: int(next(iter(x))), reverse=True)`

Comment: @JonSG I think your response is also sorting based on superkey values , I tried your response although it is sorting perfectly for above 3 inputs but in case i have more inputs it isn't working perfectly for them

Comment: @wjandrea No it isn't same as the link mentioned by you.

Comment: You need to provide a real example of what you want sorted.

Comment: @amnpawar In what way? Please [edit] to clarify, like "I had a look at [link] but it doesn't work because [reason]". And please provide a [mre]. A bunch of your code seems to be irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: @JonSG I have edited the question and have provided more count values in the Output over which I am applying this filter. As you can see some values gets sorted as 4 is coming at top but in mid 21 and other values are still not in order